# Cross site Scripting in HTTP Method?

Tags: http, javascript, xss, ajax

Lately, I've noticed that many web server configurations reflect the method of an HTTP request sent with a non implemented method in the body of the server's response.

For example, A request sent with the method GETTT will be responded with a 501 "method not implemented" response code, while the body of the response announces that the method "GETTT" is not supported.
From what I understand, this means that if the method sent to the web server is not properly validated it can be vulnerable to a reflected XSS attack.

My question is, how can an attacker take advantage of this type of situation to create a link that will cause an HTTP request to be issued with an arbitrary method containing XSS payload?
In theory, jquery $ajax requests should be able to handle this type of issue, as also stated in the following discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20425594/sending-an-http-request-with-an-unordinary-method/

I was able to send these type of requests several months ago (In Internet Explorer), but for some reason, jquery $ajax does do the trick for me anymore.

I'm sure this is a solvable issue and just a matter of finding the right payload, does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Did you include the javascript library?

Comment: Have you tried setting the "Method" attribute of a form to your XSS payload? I haven't tried it myself but i think it's worth a shot. It would defeat the purpose of XSS though i guess

Comment: I did include the jquery library using script src=, and and HTML form only supports the GET and POST methods. any other method would result in the form being submitted using POST.

Comment: I suppose most XHR implementations restrict valid HTTP methods to at least [what the HTTP specification allows, i. e., a *token* (one or more of `!`, `#`, `$`, `%`, `&`, `'`, `*`, `+`, `-`, `.`, `0`–`9`, `@`, `A`–`Z`, `^`, `\`, `_`, `a`–`z`, and `~`)](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-5.1.1). But I think it’s even more restricted, like, to only uppercase `A`–`Z` and `-`.

Comment: Erratum: Without `@`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer:  **Not exploitable**

Although it maybe possible to inject script code using a malformed HTTP verb, this attack vector is missing the "cross-site"  component which makes the vulnerability useful to an attacker.   So, why would an injection like this be useless to an attacker?

Well first of all how does an attacker send a "cross-site" request?  There are a couple of variants,  but the most common is as follows.

```
<form id="CSRF" method="POST"  action="http://victim/search" >
<type=hidden name=search value="<script>alert(1)</script>">
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("CSRF").submit()
</script>
```

The HTML above will automatically send a POST request when the victim renders the HTML.  The page `http://victim/search` is reflecting the search POST request on the page,  thus executing the XSS payload in the victim's browser in the context of `http://victim/search` regardless of where the request originated from.

It is possible to control some of the HTTP header using flash, so I wrote a [flash exploit framework to leverage unusual CSRF/XSS](https://github.com/TheRook/CSRF-Request-Builder).  Unfortunately flash currently only permit the `GET` and `POST` verbs,  `PUT` and `DELETE` where allowed at once upon a time,  but no longer.